# Nonhomogenous linear system (undetermined coefficients)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

*Find the general solution of
$$\bar{x}' =  \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -5 \\
  1 & -2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} \bar{x} + \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ cost \\ \end{pmatrix}, \: 0<t<\pi$$*

I find the general solution to the homogenous equation by finding the eigenvectors to the matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -5 \\
  1 & -2 \\
 \end{pmatrix} $$
I then want to use the method of undetermined coefficients to find a particular solution. But I'm not getting anywhere with the assumption $$\bar{x} = \bar{a}sin t + \bar{b}cos t$$ Have I assumed the wrong form for the particular solution and if so why is it wrong?

Comment: Note that the solution of the corresponding homogeneous system also contains terms like $sint$  and $cost$.